# What Was the Messenger of Satan That Tormented Paul?

Tags: luke, acts, paul, galatians, satan

The apostle Paul describes being tormented by a "messenger of Satan":

> **2 Corinthians 12:7**: “Because of the surpassing greatness of the revelations, for this reason, to keep me from exalting myself, there was given me a thorn in the flesh, **a messenger of Satan to torment me** – to keep me from exalting myself!” [NAS]

Some of the theories suggested for the source of Paul's torment include:

> - Temptation,
> - Chronic eye problems,
> - Malaria,
> - Migraines,
> - Epilepsy, and,
> - Someone (such as Alexander the coppersmith, 2 Tim. 4:14).

Of course, there are other reasons cited, but I'm unconvinced that this has been satisfactorily addressed from a ***spiritual*** perspective. Of course, it may never be revealed in this life, but I believe it's worthy of further pursuit.